# How to get coordinates of the *result* of perspective transform?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Tl;dr** Given an `image`, `patch_size` and `warp_mat`, I would like to compute the coordinates of the patch "extracted" from the image, after applying `cv2.warpPerspective`.

In more details:

If my goal was to crop a specific area from the image, and squeeze it into a different-sized patch, then I know how to do it using `getPerspectiveTransform`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

smiley = cv2.imread('icon.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(smiley.shape)
# (255, 255)
plt.imshow(smiley, cmap='gray');
left, upper, right, lower = 120, 50, 190, 100
plt.plot([left, right, right, left, left], [upper, upper, lower, lower, upper]);
```

[image: smiley with cropping area]

```
w, h = 40, 50
src = np.array([[left, upper], [right, upper], [right, lower], [left, lower]], dtype=np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0, 0], [w, 0], [w, h], [0, h]], dtype=np.float32)
warp_mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
print(warp_mat)
# [[  0.571   0.    -68.571]
#  [  0.      1.    -50.   ]
#  [ -0.     -0.      1.   ]]
warp_patch = cv2.warpPerspective(smiley, warp_mat, (w, h))
plt.imshow(warp_patch, cmap='gray');
```

[image: patch]

**Finally, my question is:**

My inputs are: `image`, `warp_mat`, `w`, `h`.

And my goal is to discover `left`, `upper`, `right`, `lower`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

```
inv_warp_mat = np.linalg.pinv(warp_mat)
left, upper, _ = inv_warp_mat @ np.array([0, 0, 1])
right, lower, _ = inv_warp_mat @ np.array([w, h, 1])
```

The longer answer:

Following [@HansHirse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333658/2934048) to this question, I understood that indeed "I only needed to multiply by the inverse", and more verbosely - multiplying the corners of the patch by the inverse warping mat, gives the corners of the patch in the original photo's coordinates - which is exactly what I was looking for.

BTW, the inaccuracies at the end of the calculation in @HansHirshes's answer were due to the `cv2.boundingRect` operation.

#### The full correct calculation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

smiley = cv2.imread('icon.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(smiley.shape)
# (255, 255)
plt.imshow(smiley, cmap='gray');
left, upper, right, lower = 120, 50, 190, 100
print(left, upper, right, lower)

w, h = 40, 50
src = np.array([[left, upper], [right, upper], [right, lower], [left, lower]], dtype=np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0, 0], [w, 0], [w, h], [0, h]], dtype=np.float32)
warp_mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
```

Now assuming we only have the `warp_mat` and the patch size:

```
inv_warp_mat = np.linalg.pinv(warp_mat)
left_inv, upper_inv, _ = inv_warp_mat @ np.array([0, 0, 1])
right_inv, lower_inv, _ = inv_warp_mat @ np.array([w, h, 1])
print(left_inv, upper_inv, right_inv, lower_inv)
```

result:

```
120 50 190 100
120.00000000000011 50.000000000000014 190.00000000000037 100.00000000000007
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Micka's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201448/11089932), "you typically just invert the transformation matrix".

With respect to your input image's size, you reconstruct your patch on an empty image, such that you can then simply use [`cv2.boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) to reconstruct the original region of interest.

I prepared some code incorporating parts of your code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

smiley = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Region of interest
left, upper, right, lower = 120, 50, 190, 100
print(left, upper, right, lower)

# Width and height
w, h = 40, 50

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1), plt.imshow(smiley, cmap='gray')
plt.plot([left, right, right, left, left], [upper, upper, lower, lower, upper])

# Source and destination points
src = np.array([[left, upper], [right, upper], [right, lower], [left, lower]], dtype=np.float32)
dst = np.array([[0, 0], [w, 0], [w, h], [0, h]], dtype=np.float32)

# Perspective transform
warp_mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warp_patch = cv2.warpPerspective(smiley, warp_mat, (w, h))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2), plt.imshow(warp_patch, cmap='gray')

# Inverse perspective transform
inv_warp_mat = np.linalg.pinv(warp_mat)
reverse = cv2.warpPerspective(warp_patch, inv_warp_mat, smiley.shape)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3), plt.imshow(reverse, cmap='gray')

# Reconstruct region of intereset
l, t, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(reverse)
left_rev = l
upper_rev = t
right_rev = l + w
lower_rev = t + h
print(left_rev, upper_rev, right_rev, lower_rev)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The print output looks like this:

```
120 50 190 100
119 50 190 100
```

And, the plot output looks like this:

[image: Plot output]

Unfortunately, the reconstructed result is not perfect, but maybe you can investigate that and find further improvements.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Matplotlib:    3.3.4
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks! The inaccuracies you have at the end are because of the `cv2.boundingRect` operation. Indeed all I needed to do was multiply the corners of the patch by the inverse warp mat...